# Cannot see default web site in iis in windows 10

Tags: windows, iis, windows-10

I got new pc in office and I had installed IIS from windows feature (on/off) and everything appears good.

When I started iis manager I can just see my pc name i.e.

> > MyPCName (MyDomainName\MyUserName)

thats it. I can't see anything else. Expanding server doesn't show anything. Right clicking on it just giving three options -

```
Refresh
Rename
Switch to Content View
```

I can't see any other option. So far I had re-installed it multiple times. and restarted my pc multiple times, but nothing changed.

Can anyone help?

Comment: When you open `localhost`, it shows IIS default welcome page? Also make sure that the `IIS Management Console` feature is explicitly checked in windows feature list.

Comment: @gofr1, yes it display home page when open localhost but no sites were displayed.